# Twitter gem - how to get the ID of a new tweet?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, twitter-gem

I am using the twitter gem to update a users status. However, I also need to know the ID of the recently created status so I can delete it later on. Any guidance here?

Answer (score 6):

Assuming you've properly [configured](https://github.com/sferik/twitter/wiki/Configuration) your Twitter client, it should be as easy as:

```
# Create a tweet
tweet = Twitter.update("I'm tweeting with @gem!")

# Delete that tweet
Twitter.status_destroy(tweet.id)
```

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to reference the id by simply appending '.id' to the returned tweet.
e.g. `Twitter.status(27558893223).id`